# Sort Raw step is not working proper in pentaho PDI

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Here i am attaching the screen-shots of the output before using sort rows step and after sorting in descending order based on "CB_LearningObjectStartTimeStamp" and "CB_UserID" fields.

You can see that ConsumerEMPLID and CB_UserID is remains same for 1 user and after sorting CB_UserID is changing for the same user in few rows in-between.

So can you tell me that am i doing something wrong in this.. how can i resolved this issue. because for 1 user ConsumerEMPLID and CB_UserID has to be remains same as it is coming proper before sorting.
[image: output after sort row step]

[image: output before using sort row step]

[image: just for reference, sorting based on starttime]

Comment: i did sorting according to CB_UserID and CB_LearningObjectStartTimeStamp.. Sorry for only mentioning CB_LearningObjectStartTimeStamp..

Comment: i see weird quotes on your fields, means you are using fields as strings, try to type the order fields as integers, remove this quotes. and try to sort again by this fields

Comment: i explicitly putted quotes.
It was working properly only with quotes also but it was my debugging mistake so i though it was not working properly but now i just corrected it and my problem is solved..
Btw thanks @jipipayo for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort rows doesn't change the data within each row. What you're seeing are most likely other rows being inserted in between. You just have to choose correctly the fields to sort. If you sort only based on that timestamp, rows will be output according to that timestamp and all other rows will be output based on the order they entered the step.

Comment: that is what i suppose to tell that if i am sorting according to time-stamp then only sequence has to be change. But i am not able to understand why data within the row is changing?
is this a bug with community edition?

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that it may be a bug. The steps for both Community and Enterprise are the same (except the very few that are EE only), so a bug in CE would also appear in EE. Furthermore, what you're seeing are probably other rows you were not expecting. Try the following to debug: 1) add a sequence, before the sort rows; Output the results to a text file. This gives you the rows and the row numbers before the sort. Output the results AFTER the sort rows to a new text file. Inspect the files and lookup the rows you think have changed.

Comment: Hey this one is great suggestion.. Thanks a lot.. Now i can see that the problem is not with tool.. (y)